# Using sed to pull certain information from a log

Tags: linux, sed, text-processing

I have this log which I would like to extract information from. I want to use `sed` to extract it.

```
Nov 12 19:56:52 libra kernel: [ 1353.27355] WarningIN=em0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c8:1b:3c:fd:5D:e9:90:a9:8F:43:83:E3:15:0e SRC=222.171.89.16 DST=49.137.111.136 LEN=222 TOS=0x8C PREC=0xbF TTL=107 ID=31469 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=35 CODE=8 ID=24917 SEQ=166

19:56:52 12 Nov;Warning;em0;eth0;222.171.89.16;49.137.111.136;ICMP;;
```

I am having trouble with my understanding of `sed`.
If someone could correct me here that would be great.
I wanted to get the date first of all so I wrote

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' file.log
```

but my output is

```
Nov 12 19:56:52
```

I am not understanding why I am not just getting the `19:56:52`

Comment: Your `sed` matching string is allowing anything up to the time specifier you have. You need to look at your log records and find something in front of the time that you can match against and then remove, e.g., `s/^(something here)\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/`. Make sure to capture from the beginning of the line (`^`) up to the time.

Comment: Can you explain why my line is allowing anything up to the time?

Comment: When I try to use a specific string in the example line you gave it outputs everything

Comment: Yes: because it's not filtering it. Anything you don't capture in the match string passes through. You will need to share what you did specifically in order to get comment on it. I can't answer your issue since I don't know what you did.

Comment: @zacgalf because that's how sed works. Consider the simple example `sed s/foo/bar/` will transform `baz foo` into `baz bar`, not `bar`

Comment: I got the date using
$ sed 's/^.*\[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/

Comment: That will work as long as it doesn't false match something else that looks like a time further to the right in the string. I had originally suggested it as an answer, then deleted it after someone pointed that out. That's why I later suggested finding something your log entries have in common between start of line and the time you want that you could put in place of that initial `.*`. Just proceed with caution. :)

Comment: this is my file 
When I use 
sed -r 's/^.*DPT=([^\ ]*).*$/\1/' file.log
a few of the lines give the entire line and I am assuming it is because i used ^.* 
How can I get the DPT value alone on all lines? Why are some of the lines not only printing the DPT values?
Also, how can I pull out the log prefix message? such as WARNING before IN=
I tried to use 
sed -n '/^....]$/,/^IN=$/p' file.log
but no luck

Comment: Aug 00 08:35:51 virgo kernel: [ 4584.5613] That's oddIN=em0 OUT=eth0 MAC=0a:09:AA:4F:6C:41:c6:De:D6:6f:83:41:8e:dC SRC=142.53.155.238 DST=252.1.134.24 LEN=506 TOS=0x11 PREC=0x5c TTL=67 ID=5098 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=35 CODE=5 ID=31329 SEQ=22
Jun 21 11:47:48 taurus kernel: [ 741.5237] Look into this IN=em1 OUT=eth0 MAC=Bd:5b:ab:b7:47:fA:df:53:0E:E8:A7:2a:f6:c6 SRC=50.219.1.59 DST=56.95.45.60 LEN=390 TOS=0xf2 PREC=0x79 TTL=122 ID=28867 PROTO=UDP SPT=16351 DPT=15354 LEN=9

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/626080/how-to-use-sed-print-the-required-content-from-each-line/626103#626103

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*\s)([0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])(.*$)/\2/'
```

Here's an example:

```
echo "Nov 12 19:56:52 libra kernel" | sed -r 's/(^.*\s)([0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])(.*$)/\2/'

=> 19:56:52
```

If you just wanted to print all of the file contents using sed then you can do so using:

```
sed r FILE
```

If you want sed to act like `grep`:

```
sed -n '/regexp/p' FILE          # method 1
sed '/regexp/!d'   FILE          # method 2
```

Or if you want it to act like `grep -v`

```
sed -n '/regexp/!p' FILE         # method 1, corresponds to above
sed '/regexp/d'     FILE         # method 2, simpler syntax
```

You can also find a whole slew of sed one-liners [here](http://www.pement.org/sed/sed1line.txt) (in fact, the grep examples above were taken from the webpage linked here--except that I added the `FILE` to each of them)

Answer (score 1):

**Simply put, you are not just getting the `19:56:52` because your pattern is not matching `Nov 12`.**

If you add `.*` to the beginning of your pattern to match the `Nov 12`, it will work as you expect. Here is the corrected command:

```
$ sed 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' file.log
```

Comment: work in this sample but could be false if an hour is in the later text

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/\([[:alpha:]]\{3\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\{0,1\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,2\}:}[0-9]\{1,2\}:}[0-9]\{1,2\}\).*/\2/p' YourFile
```

take the first hour if (one of the case)

- is after the month / day in date format (Nov 12 ) that start the line
- is after space (if any) at start of line

and print it

Does not take the hour is somewhere else or with other template (and don't print the line)